# HTTP load failing due to strict content length - expected: 3732, received: 2661, received (uncompressed): 0

Tags: swift, httprequest

I have a problem with executing an HTTP requests in Swift 4.2 when the content requested is getting longer then a couple of rows in a table. I am developing an app that needs to display an overview of 30 - 40 rows which each contain 4-5 variables.

I am using an HTTPRequest to fetch the data from a remote server and then rendering it in a tableview in a UIViewController.

As I do so, the request sometimes completes and sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't I'm getting this message in the console,

> HTTP load failing due to strict content length - expected: 3732,
>   received: 2661, received (uncompressed): 0

I have tried smaller requests which complete fine every time. The problem is that I have pruned the response from the server to be as small as possible but still I have this problem.

I thought this might be related to NSAppTransportSecurity so I tried setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in info.plist to true which changed nothing.

I use json.dumps on the flask side to send the data over. I tried also creating a Request instance with the content-length set but that had no effect. I tried jsonify as well but no change.

I have googled quite a bit w/o finding an question / answer which explains why this happens further.

For clarification, this is what the answer from the server looks like:

```
[["weight_unit": "kg", "actual_reps": 6, "no_calories": 82, "date": 2019-09-13, "actual_excercise_id": deadlift_with_bar, "weight": 50], ["weight_unit": "kg", "actual_reps": 6, "no_calories": 82, "date": 2019-09-13, "actual_excercise_id": deadlift_with_bar, "weight": 50], ["weight_unit": "kg", "actual_reps": 6, "no_calories": 82, "date": 2019-09-13, "actual_excercise_id": deadlift_with_bar, "weight": 50], ["weight_unit": "kg", "actual_reps": 8, "no_calories": 82, "date": 2019-09-13, "actual_excercise_id": deadlift_with_bar, "weight": 50], ["weight_unit": lb, "actual_reps": 6, "no_calories": 82, "date": 2019-09-13, "actual_excercise_id": squat_machine, "weight": 35], ["weight_unit": lb, "actual_reps": 10, "no_calories": 82, "date": 2019-09-13, "actual_excercise_id": squat_machine, "weight": 75], ["weight_unit": lb, "actual_reps": 10, "no_calories": 82, "date": 2019-09-13, "actual_excercise_id": squat_machine, "weight": 95]]
```

As explained above, it sometimes reaches the app and sometimes doesn't.

The post request code:

```
   static func makeHTTPRequest(path:String, data:[String:Any], onSuccess: ((_ response:[String: Any]) -> Void)?) {
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let url_str = path
        let url = URL(string: url_str)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                    if json["answer"] as! String == "ok"
                    {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let onSuccess = onSuccess {
                                onSuccess(json)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find an explanation for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I was however able to resolve many of my problems by using GET requests instead of POST. Apparently they don't have these limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. It turned out that the API guys had a bug in calculating content-lenght header. Unless server returns "chunked", the response size need to be calculated properly.
I would use `Insomnia` or other tool like `Postman` to debug the http response for different scenarios(long and short request).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I downloaded Postman but I've never used it before. No matter how often I post the request, I always get statuscode 200 back and everything works fine. This appears to be a SWIFT / iOS related matter as I see it since I have used python and flask for many years without experiencing this problem. How would you recommend debugging this in Postman?

Comment: @st0ne Probably too late to help, but try using Paw instead of postman, and change your settings to use AppleURLSession instead of PawHttpLibrary. I suggest this because it is the same (or similar) http library being used by iOS webviews and Safari and so if it's an iOS specific issue it will replicate in Paw.